# If $(3)=\mathfrak p_3\mathfrak p_3'$ then we can write $\mathfrak p_3=(3,1+\sqrt{17})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> Why if $(3)=\mathfrak p_3\mathfrak p_3'$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]$ then we can write $\mathfrak p_3=(3,1+\sqrt{-17})$

I saw [here](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ant06/anth04a.pdf) in the first exercise that the author already knows how to decompose $(3)$, does it something to do with the Legendre symbol ? In the second exercise it is also $+1$ and the same decomposition appears.

Is the other prime ideal then $\mathfrak p_3'=(3,1-\sqrt{-17})$ ?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\ideal}[1]{{\mathfrak #1}}$
$\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\mathbb Z}}$
$\newcommand{\QQ}{{\mathbb Q}}$
$\newcommand{\FF}{{\mathbb F}}$

As $\ZZ[\sqrt{-17}]$ is the ring of algebraic integers in $\QQ(\sqrt{-17})$ ($-17 \equiv 3\mod 4$) one can apply the identity

$$\ZZ[\sqrt{-17}]/p \ZZ[\sqrt{-17}] = \ZZ[x]/(x^2+17, p) = \FF_p[x]/(x^2+17)$$

So if $x^2+17$ is prime modulo $p$ in $\FF_p[x]$ then $p$ is inert.
If it splits into $f_1(x) f_2(x)$ with $f_1,f_2$ linear and different, then

$$p \ZZ[\sqrt{-17}] = (p, f_1(\sqrt{-17})) (p, f_2(\sqrt{-17}))$$

This splitting happens exactly when $-17$ is a square modulo $p$, so the Legendre symbol governs the splitting.

From $x^2 + 17 = (x+1)  (x-1) \mod 3$ we get in the special case $p=3$

$$p \ZZ[\sqrt{-17}] = (3,1+\sqrt{-17}) (3,-1+\sqrt{17})$$

so your thought about $\ideal{p}_3'$ is true.